# widget.NewMultiLineEntry(): How to scroll to the bottom?

Tags: go, fyne

I'm using `widget.NewMultiLineEntry()` in my GUI application to create a multi-line text entry widget. I'm looking for a way to automatically or manually scroll to the bottom of the widget whenever new content is added. How can I achieve this behavior? Is it even possible?

```golang
logsBox := widget.NewMultiLineEntry()
logsBox.Wrapping = fyne.TextTruncate
logsBox.SetMinRowsVisible(3)
logsBox.SetPlaceHolder("Waiting for logs...")
logsBox.OnChanged = func(newMsg string) {
    // ...
}

logsBox.SetText("Row 1\nRow 2\nRow 3\nRow 4")
// TODO: Scroll to the bottom manually somehow?
```

Comment: It’s probably worth noting that a log widget that is build using a single entry widget may not have good performance as the number of lines grows. Every time you append it will have to parse the content for all the newlines before updating - which could get slow.

Comment: @andy.xyz thanks for the heads up, mate. You and other Fyne contributors built something fantastic — my sincere appreciation. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like we can use `CursorRow` property to solve this:

```golang
focusedItem := logsWindow.Canvas().Focused()
// If the user is not focused on the text area then scroll to the end
if focusedItem == nil || focusedItem != logsBox {
    logsBox.CursorRow = len(logsBox.Text) - 1 // Sets the cursor to the end
}
```